# python check if values exist in list

Tags: python

couldn't get this correct.  I want to check the contents of the list for a set of values.  I should not be falling inside the conditional if because the value doesn't exist.

Following list contains:
['pm_pmdo', 'pm_pmco', 'shv', 'dsv', 'pmv']

Checking for the following: she, dse, pme

inside found one?

```
class newfunc(object):

    def testfunction(self):

        self.DSE = 'dse'
        self.PME = 'pme'
        self.SHE = 'she'

        self.users_roles = ['pm_pmdo', 'pm_pmco', 'shv', 'dsv', 'pmv']

        print 'Following list contains:'
        print self.users_roles
        print 'Checking for the following:'
        print self.SHE
        print self.DSE
        print self.PME

        if (self.DSE or self.PME or self.SHE for s in self.users_roles):
        #if (self.DSE or self.PME or self.SHE) in self.users_roles:
            print "inside found one"
        else:
            print "outside none found"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runtime = newfunc()
    runtime.testfunction()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if any(role in self.users_roles for role in (self.SHE, self.PME, self.SHE)):
```

Answer (score 1):

[`sets`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) are good containers for quick membership testing if order doesn't matter:

```
class NewFunc(object):
    def testfunction(self):
        self.DSE = 'dse'
        self.PME = 'pme'
        self.SHE = 'she'

        self.users_roles = {'pm_pmdo', 'pm_pmco', 'shv', 'dsv', 'pmv'}

        print 'users_roles:'
        print list(self.users_roles)
        print 'Checking for the following:'
        print self.SHE
        print self.DSE
        print self.PME

        if {self.DSE, self.PME, self.SHE} & self.users_roles:
            print "found at least one"
        else:
            print "none found"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runtime = NewFunc()
    runtime.testfunction()
```

Comment: @DSM: Sorry...accidental.

Answer (score 0):

Use `any` which short circuits returning True if we do find a match or evaluates to False otherwise:

```
if any(s in self.users_roles for s in (self.DSE , self.PME , self.SHE ))
```

Your code always evaluates to `True` as `if self.DSE` is basically checking `if bool(self.DSE)`  which will always evaluate to `True` for any non empty string, it is the same for `self.PME` and `self.SHE`.

```
In [21]: bool("foo") # will be the same for all non empty strings
Out[21]: True

In [22]: bool("")
Out[22]: False
```

You can also make `self.users_roles` a set and use `set.intersection`:

```
self.users_roles = {'pm_pmdo', 'pm_pmco', 'shv', 'dsv', 'pmv'}

if self.users_roles.intersection([self.DSE, self.PME, self.SHE])
```

Comment: Ouch.. So something like this would also be a big no no?   if self.PME has a vailue then -  if (self.PME) in self.users_roles:                           Thanks!

Comment: @DaveJones, unless you always want the if to evaluate to True for every non empty string possible then yes  it is a big no no ;) The only way it would ever be False if if you got pass empty strings. If you are doing a lot of checks the set will be much more efficient than using any. The correct way to write it would be `if  self.DSE in self.users_roles or self.PME in self.users_roles etc...` but that gets pretty ugly when you have a few to check so any is just a more concise way to do it.